# operator as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, operators

Is it possible?

```
template<operator Op> int Calc(int a, b)
{ return a Op b; }

int main()
{ cout << Calc<+>(5,3); }
```

If not, is way to achieve this without ifs and switches?

Comment: (int a, b) -> (int a, int b). http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=141

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use functors for this:

```
template<typename Op> int Calc(int a, int b)
{
    Op o;
    return o(a, b);
}

Calc<std::plus<int>>(5, 3);
```

Comment: @xir: Note that passing it as a function argument instead of as a template argument like Dario shows gives the user more freedom, e.g. to pass stateful functors, `bind()` expressions, ...

Comment: Could just be `return Op()(a, b);`, but like Georg says it's more flexible if you accept it as a parameter.

Comment: Hint: `std::plus` and friends are defined in the [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) header.

Comment: What impact will this have on CPU time? How much slower will such an operation execute compared to using the native operator?

Comment: @Silicomancer I wouldn't expect to see any difference, std::plus should get inlined and at that point the code is using the builtin operator.

Answer (score 20):

No - templates are about *types* or *primitive values*.

You can nontheless pass so called *function objects* that can be called like functions and carry the desired operator functionality (despite having a nice syntax).

The standard library defines several ones, e.g. [`std::plus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) for addition ...

```
#include <functional>

template<typename Op>
int Calc(int a, int b, Op f) { 
  return f(a, b);
}

int main() { 
  cout << Calc(5,3, std::plus());
  cout << Calc(5,3, std::minus());
}
```

Comment: What impact will this have on CPU time? How much slower will such an operation execute compared to using the native operator?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using polymorphism:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Operator
{
public:
    virtual int operator()(int a, int b) const = 0;
};

class Add : public Operator
{
public:
    int operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
        return a+b;
    }
};

class Sub : public Operator
{
public:
    int operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
        return a-b;
    }
};

class Mul : public Operator
{
public:
    int operator()(int a, int b) const
    {
        return a*b;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Add adder;
    cout << adder(1,2) << endl;
    Sub suber;
    cout << suber(1,2) << endl;
    Mul muler;
    cout << muler(1,2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct. But to show this is really useful, you'll have to actually use the runtime polymorphism and use an `Operator&` interface. Implement `Calc` for that matter. Nontheless +1 in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to global operators, you have already received some answers. In some particular cases, though, it might also be helpful to use overloaded operator functions.

This might be trivial; nevertheless it might be helpful in some cases which is why I post one example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename opType, typename T>
int operation(opType op, T a, T b)
{
    return (a.*op)(1) + (b.*op)(1);
}

struct linear
{
    int operator()(int n) const {return n;}
    int operator[](int n) const {return n * 10;}
};

int main()
{
    linear a, b;

    std::cout << operation(&linear::operator(), a, b) << std::endl
        << operation(&linear::operator[], a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2
20
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
template<typename Op>
int Calc(int a, int b, Op f) {
    return f(a, b);
}

int
main() {
    cout << Calc(5, 3, std::plus{});
    cout << Calc(5, 3, std::minus{});
}
```

if Dario answer fails with `error: cannot deduce template arguments for ‘plus’ from ()`