# Can I generate templates based on opeators?

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I'm wondering if I can use templates to create generic code for operators. Consider a simplified example which demonstrates what I'm attempting to do.

```
template<operator O>
int do_thing(int a, int b) {
  return a O b;
}

int main() {
  // expected to return 10
  int foo = do_thing<operator+>(7, 3);

  // expected to return 4
  int bar = do_thing<operator->(7, 3);

  return 0;
}
```

Am I able to express something like this? I have several functions which are identical barring a single operation which differs between them and I feel there must be a way to express that more cleanly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735398/operator-as-template-parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "operator+" as template parameter, but you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// do_thing
template<typename operator_t, typename type_t>
auto do_thing(const type_t& a, const type_t& b)
{
    // create temp inst
    return operator_t::op(a, b);
}

// template for operator
template<typename type_t>
struct plus_t
{
    static auto op(const type_t& a, const type_t& b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // specialize operator for int
    using plus = plus_t<int>;

    // do your thing
    auto value = do_thing<plus>(2, 3);
    std::cout << "result of do_thing<plus>(2,3) = " << value << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest making it `auto operator()(const type_t& a, const type_t& b)` instead and then `return operator_t{}(a, b);`. That way it'd be useful with the standard functional operator types too.

Comment: Dang I had that, decided to go for this proposal to make it a little more readable.
I thought the creation of the temporary would be confusing :) But yeah I agree